# Get parameter name/value using rs:StoredParametersID key?

Tags: c#, soap, reporting-services

I'm working with SSRS 2008 R2 with the [ReportService2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.aspx) soap endpoint with the [ReportExecutionService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.aspx).

For parameters that have large values, SSRS has some smarts to automatically tokenize a drill-down report URL ([summed up nicely in this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/a8fb313c-efce-42dc-b28b-67f695a8c791/)):

> The problem is related to the RS System Property
>   StoredParametersThreshold.  This value (defaults to 1500) determine
>   the number of characters a URL can contain before SSRS replaces that
>   URL with a token.  The reason for this functionality is that some
>   browsers/servers limit the URL length of a URL.  Since report
>   parameter value combinations can be really long, we try to be smart
>   and tokenize the URL so that the URLs will work.  A possible work
>   around is to increase the value of StoredParametersThreshold.

The URL (decoded for easier viewing) looks something like this:

```
http://iprod-ssrs/ReportServer?http://iprod-reports/admin/web/Report+Library/Drill-down+Companyids.rdl&rs:StoredParametersID=cjesl5vk0y2tbv55e1qjrz55&rs:ParameterLanguage=&rc:Parameters=Collapsed
```

The problem is, in my custom viewer, I cannot use these tokenized URLs and need to retrieve the actual parameter name/value so that I may execute the drill-down report.

Is it possible to get the parameter values using the `rs:StoredParametersID` key?

Comment: According to this post from 2010 you can't retrieve the actual parameters http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/6809f9e3-b411-4f05-96a6-47e273220a70 though maybe that's changed. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post from 2010 you can't retrieve the actual parameters http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/6809f9e3-b411-4f05-96a6-47e273220a70 though maybe that's changed. Good luck!